# What do I need for Debugging?

Tags: debugging

I just ordered a 6502, breadboards, eeprom, ...

Now where I bought those things to build my own "Computer" on breadboards, I am afraid of not being able to find errors, because I have no other microcontroller or logic analyzer.

Now my question is what do I need for debugging on my breadboards, I spent around 130$ on the other things, therefore the debugger/logic analyzer/microcontroller shouldn't be to expensive?

Comment: It really depends what type of circuit you are trying to debug. Measurement tools tend to be the most expensive things in the toolbox...in general, an oscilloscope is most important but they are some of the most priciest pieces equipment. You want a multi-meter at least but that won't help you in many cases. It's mainly to check for bad connections. A debugger is only for digging into microcontroller code. A logic analyzer is very useful when you need it but an oscilloscope can be used in a pinch and is more useful all-around.

Comment: You could get an Arduino and PICAXE which is really fast to learn and easy to program and use that. Or get an FTDI USB-UART bridge cable so you can plug your 6502's UART into the PC so you can send messages through to terminal software. It makes things way way easier since after you get the UART working you can get your MCU to spit out messages and specific points in your software so you if it is reaching that point and what values it has.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I oscilloscope would be a good investment, but I just want to try out that very low level way of building something, therefore it is way to expensive

Comment: @DKNguyen can I to the same with an arduino like with a salae logic analyzer?

Comment: Not easily and not worth it. You're overestimating the utility of a logic analyzer at your point. The way you would use the Arduino would be to code it to latch an LED on if it detects a specific event. You want it really easy to code so you aren't debugging things for both the Arduino and your 6502. Depending on what you are doing, you could get the 6502 to drive LED lights directly and skip the Arduino but this won't work in all cases (like for serial message debugging). For UART you could use the FTDI USB-UART bridge, but this won't work for I2C or SPI.

Comment: So you mean something like if pin 1 is high and pin 2 is low then turn on a LED for example?

Comment: Yeah. that's just a trivial example. In reality, for something that simple you could just make the 6502 drive LEDs directly. You would use the Arduino for something a bit more complicated, like detecting a sequence or pulse-width from the 6502 since your eyes wouldn't be fast enough to see an LED blinking that quickly.

Comment: @DKNguyen thank you. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @MP13 It's really nice to see DK's exchange with you. I've a couple of initial thoughts I wanted to add. And a question. The question is: *Is this an NMOS or CMOS 6502?* The reason I ask is that you did not say 65C02, but 6502. If you have an NMOS 6502 then you'll need to be very careful about the clock generation (or buy a module.) Which gets to a thought.

Comment: @jonk I bought a W65C02. Is that a good one?

Comment: @MP13 I had to borrow scopes, decades back. So it was hard to diagnose problems until the MCU was actually running. And failed clocking is really hard to find if you don't have good tools. So invest in doing your best quality work (and study beforehand) in creating the clocking for your MCU. If it "just works" you've bridged a big gap when you don't have logic analyzers and scopes to work with.

Comment: @MP13 I suspect that's a Western Digital CMOS. Western Digital pretty much owns the entire 6502 intellectual property now. So yes, it's a "good one" if it really did come from Western Digital. It should also come with all that's needed to generate the clocking (except you'll need a resistor of about 200k and two caps of about 47 pF -- along with a crystal of perhaps 1 MHz.)

Comment: @jonk Is it possible  to do single stepping via button on this w65c02?

Comment: @MP13 Yes. I've done it, anyway, on similar CMOS devices before. This means a more complicated clocking system. And that means more chances to screw things up royally. But you'll want, then, an external oscillator (do not attempt to use the internal one) and some logic that allows you to either gate the full speed clocking or else use only your single step logic.

Comment: @jonk thanks for your help

Comment: @MP13 Spend a lot of time making sure of everything you'll need when making your single-stepping clocking system. That means study the details you find on the web, ask questions, make absolutely sure of your skills at soldering or wire-wrapping or whatever, and do NOT hook up your W65C02 until you've verified your clock chain that leads up to it. You can find adequate kits for working with your W65C02 logic because it is all low speed stuff. US$20 or so should be enough on ebay. Hmm. [Found this](http://wilsonminesco.com/6502primer/ClkGen.html) on clocking and single-stepping.